# Installation Issue with FreeBSD 12.0 CURRENT & 11.1 Installation on AMD EPYC (BIOS - RSW1005E)

Tags: cpu, unix, bios, freebsd

Tried several times to install FreeBSD 11.1 and 12.0 CURRENT on AMD EPYC processor(EPYC 32 core devices (7601)) with BIOS - RSW1005E, installation is getting failed.

For 11.1, Kernel Crash is happening, system is rebooting and for 12.0 CURRENT, its not crashing but installation getting failed.

Attaching the screenshots for more details.

Tried upgrading/downgrading and tried with changing options suggested in some forums,enabled/disabled components but no luck.

Kindly help us in installing the FreeBSD 11.1 & 12.0 CURRENT on AMD EPYC Processor.

Steps or process to be followed would be great if someone provide us.

NOTE: As workaround we tried FreeBSd installation 11.X on the 1p Diesel machine(1P,EPYC 7351-16core) , I am able to install FreeBSD with latest BIOS. I think our issue is with FreeBSD not working with 2P systems. Can someone suggest on this. We will have to dig deeper as to understand why 2P(EPYC 32 core devices (7601)) is not supported. Is it due to FreeBSD OS not having the support for 2P systems or some issue from AMD side.

Appreciate your quick help.

Thanks,
Surya[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRe69.jpg)